# Why is executing a ruby command on bash to command file not working?

Tags: ruby, bash

Code from .command file:

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")" 
g1=Hi-Lo
echo Welcome to Ruby_Games! So far, you can play $g1.
echo What game would you like to play?
read game_choice
if [$game_choice == $g1]
then
ruby Hi-Lo.rb
fi
```

Output:

```
Welcome to Ruby_Games! So far, you can play Hi-Lo.
What game would you like to play?
Hi-Lo
/Users/Abbas/Desktop/Ruby_Games/LAUNCHER.command: line 6: [Hi-Lo: command not found
logout
```

So what exactly is going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need double quotes in your if statement

Similar to example 6.4 here: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")" 
g1=Hi-Lo
echo Welcome to Ruby_Games! So far, you can play $g1.
echo What game would you like to play?
read game_choice
if [ "$game_choice" = "$g1" ]
then
    ruby Hi-Lo.rb
fi
```

Comment: i actually did use the quotes before. But I think i used them wrong so i thought i should not use them. But i realised how you used the quotes is the correct way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need spaces between each element of the `test` (aka `[`) command. That is, you need a space between `[` and `$game_choice`, between `$game_choice` and  `=`, etc. Also, as @GregHNZ pointed out, you should use double-quotes around variable references, in case they contain spaces or certain other shell metacharacters. Finally, `==` in a `test` expression is a bash extension; use `=` instead, and it'll work in more basic shells as well. Result:

```
if [ "$game_choice" = "$g1" ]
```

Spaces are important delimiters in shell syntax; there are places they're required and places they're forbidden, and very very few places where they're optional. In many languages, you can add or remove spaces to make the code more readable, but that's not the case in shell.

BTW, I recommend using [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net); it does a pretty good job of spotting errors like this. Actually, it points out a couple I didn't think of: you should add a shebang line to the beginning of the script, and using `cd` without checking for an error risks the rest of the script running in an unexpected directory. So you should use something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")" || {
    echo "Error cd'ing to the script's directory" >&2
    exit 1
}
```